# How to use iis7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have created a web site using Visual Studio 2010.
I have never used IIS 7 before and i know almost nothing about it.
Could someone explain me step by step how to upload my site?
I have searched about it at: http://www.iis.net/ ,but i found this site really confusing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 links for you to check out. One has some good videos on IIS 7 and the other is some reading for you. Hopefully these will help ya out a bit more.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2008/11/14/learn-iis7-short-tutorial-videos-available-on-iis-net-plus-more.aspx

http://programming4.us/security/614.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up the Web Site on your server of course.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx

Now publish your website. Just right click on the project and then choose Publish.  If you publish using File System you can pick a local folder where all the files are stored - then upload using any FTP program or I usually synch using DreamWeaver.

Hope this helps.